# Adding an extra in column into 2D numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array that has a shape of `(867, 43)`. My aim is to add an extra column (np.nan value) as the leading column to this array so that the shape becomes `(867, 44)`.

An example would be:

```
# sub-section of array
>>> arr[:2, :5]

array([[-0.30368954,  2.8808107 ,  5.8833385 ,  8.6606045 , 11.242557  ],
       [-0.22719575,  3.0030012 ,  6.065371  ,  8.924864  , 11.561942  ]],
  dtype=float32)
```

would turn into:

```
# same sub-section
>>> f[:2,:5]

array([[        nan, -0.30368954,  2.8808107 ,  5.8833385 ,  8.6606045 ],
       [        nan, -0.22719575,  3.0030012 ,  6.065371  ,  8.924864  ]],
  dtype=float32)
```

i.e the values have been shifted right as the horizontal dimension has increased by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [np.insert()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr
array([[-0.30368954,  2.8808107 ,  5.8833385 ,  8.6606045 , 11.242557  ],
       [-0.22719575,  3.0030012 ,  6.065371  ,  8.924864  , 11.561942  ]],

>>> arr = np.insert(arr, 0, np.nan, axis=0)
>>> arr
array([[        nan, -0.30368954,  2.8808107 ,  5.8833385 ,  8.6606045 , 11.242557  ],
       [        nan, -0.22719575,  3.0030012 ,  6.065371  ,  8.924864  , 11.561942  ]],
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about insert. Normally use stack for all this stuff. Learning something new everyday

Comment: No problem! Your stack example was going to be my fallback option. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). Edit: clarification; I am making use of the [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature to insert a newaxis along the second dimension and hstack will then append the axis along the zero axis (default for hstack is rows or first dimension).

```
from numpy import array, hstack, nan, newaxis
a = array([[-0.30368954,  2.8808107 ,  5.8833385 ,  8.6606045 , 11.242557  ],
       [-0.22719575,  3.0030012 ,  6.065371  ,  8.924864  , 11.561942  ]],
  dtype=float32)

tmp = ones((a.shape[0])) * nan # create nan array
print(hstack((tmp[:, newaxis], a))) # append along zero axis
```

Output:

```
[[        nan -0.30368954  2.88081074  5.88333845  8.66060448 11.24255657]
 [        nan -0.22719575  3.00300121  6.06537104  8.92486382 11.5619421 ]]
```

Comment: that works! However I'm sure there would be a way to do it which is a bitter clearer to whats going on... I'm trying to see if I can get numpy.insert to work in one line but I haven't got it to work yet..

Comment: addded some more info for you! And cleaned it up with the required nan array. Either using the newaxis or None. It is equivalent to specify a 1 in the shape of the ones method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.hstack()`:

```
import numpy as np

my_arr = np.array([[-0.30368954,  2.8808107 ,  5.8833385 ,  8.6606045 , 11.242557  ],
                [-0.22719575,  3.0030012 ,  6.065371  ,  8.924864  , 11.561942  ]])

col = np.empty((my_arr.shape[0],1))
col[:] = np.nan
np.hstack((col, my_arr))
```

Returns:

```
[[        nan -0.30368954  2.8808107   5.8833385   8.6606045  11.242557  ]
 [        nan -0.22719575  3.0030012   6.065371    8.924864   11.561942  ]]
```